# SherlockNavigationDrawer (implements actionbarsherlock)

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

i am trying to modify the example from SherlockNavigationDrawer. It has only one fragment but i have no idea about to add more fragments each one with his own layout, not the same for all...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
    frame.setId(CONTENT_VIEW_ID);
    setContentView(frame, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        setInitialFragment();
    }
}


private void setInitialFragment() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(CONTENT_VIEW_ID, MainFragment.newInstance()).commit();
}
```

But my idea is to call a new fragment when clicking an item from the listview which is inside the MainFragment

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mContent.setText(Shakespeare.DIALOGUE[position]);
        mActionBar.setTitle(Shakespeare.TITLES[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(listView);

       //START A NEW FRAGMENT HERE DEPENDING OF THE POSITION CLICKED
    }
}
```

Any idea for it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Tick my answer if it helped you... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the sherlockFragment, ie, the only fragment that comes with the example.

```
public class MainFragment extends SherlockFragment {
  Customfragment1 fragment1;
  Customfragment2fragment2;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragment1 = new ContactsFragment();
    fragment2 = new GroupsFragment();
  }

      private void selectItem(int position) {

            FragmentTransaction ft = getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            // Locate Position
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1, "Customfragment1");
                ft.addToBackStack("Customfragment1");
                break;
            case 1:
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2, "Customfragment2");
                ft.addToBackStack("Customfragment2");
                break;
            }
            ft.commit();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(listView);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks amalBit, but your method selectItem i've put inside my second and third fragment.... it works but this solution it force me to put this code inside each additional fragment i create, i mean, the second one, third one.....

```
//MainFragment
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mContent.setText(Shakespeare.DIALOGUE[position]);
        mActionBar.setTitle(Shakespeare.TITLES[position]);
        //mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(listView);

        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // Locate Position
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        ft.replace(666, SecondFragment.newInstance(), "SecondFragment");
        ft.addToBackStack("SecondFragment");
        break;
    case 1:
        ft.replace(666, ThirdFragment.newInstance(), "ThirdFragment");
        ft.addToBackStack("ThirdFragment");
        break;
    }
    ft.commit();
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(listView);
}
```

Is there any chance to move this code to the controller MainActivity?

Comment: More or less... the problem now is that i'm carryng fragments on stack when i navigate between them... Should i call finish() after selecting the the new fragment?

Comment: Got my own solution for now, please check https://github.com/sebastianroming/DrawerExample - Example of starting Activities AND/OR Fragments.